# Sequelize : Get Subquery/Raw Query as model for include

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have gone through the Sequelize doc, but can't find anything helpful

What I want to do is to add raw query or custom model in `include`, is it possible ?

```
model.Post.findAll({
            include: [{
                    model: model.User,
                    attributes: ['fullname', 'profilepic'],
                },
                {
                    model: model.PostComments,
                },
                {
                    model: "Raw Query"
                }
            ]
        }
```

What I want to achieve is like :

```
Select post_id, count(*) as total_likes from post_likes group by post_id
```

I can't achieve this by using simply `include`, so what I want to do is create a table/model from above query and then use it inside include.

If I use group by withing `include` it gives group by from top level, and I want to apply `group` by just for the `post_like` table.

Please let me know, if it found confusing or not clear.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @pkyeck , nope :( , I ended up by using raw query.

Comment: Don't think it can be done, these are the options and https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll include forces an existing Model as part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to do the same, use a **raw query** dynamically formed inside the **include** but there's no possible way to use **include** without a model https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll .

For the purposes of my MySQL I turned my **inner join** (include) into a **where in**. I was doing the **inner join** to avoid the exception `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery` . I get this exception because I have a subquery with LIMIT applied.

If it helps anyone:

```
let rows = await j_model.findAll({
        attributes: [...j_columns, `${association}.meta_key_id`],
        include: [
            {
                model: um_model,
                as: association,
                attributes: ['um_id'],
                on: {'j_id' : {$col: 'j.j_id'} }
        ],
        where: {'j_id': {$in: sequelize.literal(`(SELECT * FROM (${massive_inner_raw_query}) as tmp)`)}},
        logging: console.log
    });
```

The **actual magic** is in this line:

```
where: {'j_id': {$in: sequelize.literal(`(SELECT * FROM (${massive_inner_raw_query}) as tmp)`)}}
```

The **SELECT * FROM** removes that exception and lets me do a **where in** instead of the wanted **INNER JOIN**. Maybe you can apply a similar deal to your problem.

Comment: How can I do it if I want to left join above only

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [[models.sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN "field1" = true THEN 55 
    ELSE 23 END'), 'field3']]
}
```

**OR**

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: { include: [[models.sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN "field1" = true THEN 55 ELSE 23 END'), 'field3']]}
}
```